# ROS on win32 laptop VM - is it possible?

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a win32 3G-RAM laptop.

I installed VM for the sake of ROS.

- Tried ubuntu 16.04, failed to install ROS on it. (unmet dependencies)
- Tried ubuntu 14.04, it is impossibly slow.
- Tried ubuntu  13.10, again, unmet dependencies that are not going to be installed.

I am new to ROS.
Is it possible to run ROS on a not-so-strong laptop?

What is the best configuration?

Thanks Tova

---

Edit: I am not worried about performance because this is for just a short project.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation  vs  #q188732  answer #1 :
The difference is with the step:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Is this step needed?

Step:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

Gives me a lot of "unmet dependencies that are not going to be installed." , on all my tries with different configurations.

Are these dependencies supposed to get met automatically?

I have a feeling that the dependencies failure has nothing to do with the performance of the machine. (Am I right?)

Thanks Tova

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252889/ros-on-win32-laptop-vm---is-it-possible?/) by [tovas](https://answers.ros.org/users/29153/tovas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-24**:
Which ROS distribution were you trying to install? I'm asking because different ROS distros are supported on different Ubuntu distros (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation)

**Comment by [tovas](https://answers.ros.org/users/29153/tovas/) on 2017-01-24**:
On ubuntu 16.04 I tried kinetic. On 13.10 I tried both kinetic and indigo.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-24**:\

> On 13.10 I tried both kinetic

Kinetic is only supported on 16.04 at the moment, so that would seem to be impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Technically: yes, this is definitely possible. There aren't any special requirements other than that the VM runs a version of Linux that is supported by ROS (and perhaps you could say that somewhat decent 3D accelerated graphics support is also required, but that is only the case if you want to run any kind of visualisation tool, like RViz).

Practically though, for all intents and purposes, I'd venture that, no, on the hw you describe, I wouldn't want to be working with a VM with ROS. As you've already found out, it's just too slow to be of practical use, and you'll just get annoyed by the long waiting times.

You could see whether adding a (cheap) SSD to the laptop improves things (if it doesn't already have one), but even then it's not a recommended solution.

If you can, go for a native (dual-boot) installation.

---

Edit:

> The VM is not likely the issue. I do nearly all of my ROS development and testing on a 2GB 1 CPU core VM. The difference being I run a 64 bit guest on a 64 bit host.

Without more information on the specific hw the OP is using it's hard to say what the problem is, but running 64bit guests on 32bit hosts is definitely not going to help performance (I'm assuming you mean: 32bit host OS on a 64bit cpu).

And it's definitely possible to run ROS on a VM, but based on the many questions I've seen on this board concerning RViz, Gazebo and performance in general, I'd not recommend it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-24**:
The VM is not likely the issue. I do nearly all of my ROS development and testing on a 2GB 1 CPU core VM. The difference being I run a 64 bit guest on a 64 bit host. It sounds like a few things may be happening with one of them being minimal hardware specs.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-25**:
I was indicating "being a virtual machine" is not an indictment. I run a 64bit guest on a 64bit host and performance and functionality is good. To be honest, I've never had an issue and didn't realize there was any bad history with ROS on a VM. The OP said 32bit host which is a limiting factor.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-25**:
For clarification, the term "host" refers to the OS running on the hardware and "guest" refers to the OS running in the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get RViz and Gazebo in a VM running you need a fast Maschine, with Opengl support. Dual boot is a better solution, key you have an old laptop.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1